# Group by avoids order by

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to list the messages by a loop as primarily last messages in PDO,
but I have a group by command too in the sql and it doesn't work as well.
I'm using group by for avoid the multiple messages in a page from same user.
So the user should see the messages as DESC but group by is avoiding ranking.

messages should be listed as (example):

```
conversation 1: last message - from
conversation 2: last message - from
conversation 3: last message - from
```

every conversation should contains unique sender name and the conversations that has new messages should be at top (DESC)

my sql code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pm 
WHERE pm_to={$session['id']} 
GROUP BY pm_from 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The pm_table structure are:

```
id         - int(11) auto_increment
pm_from    - int(11)
pm_to      - int(11)
pm_content - text
```

Comment: Please share the table structure at least.

Comment: You are getting unacurrate answers because your question is, after all, unclear. Please edit your post and show us some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @GMB Sorry, it's because my english :)) I updated the post

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto PDO

Comment: I understand as PDO a database access library or method, not a table / database structure. If I don't know the fields on your table "pm_from", I cannot give you a correct answer about how to GROUP and ORDER results from these table.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto I see, table structure has pm_from, pm_to and pm_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting the last message from each user to a gived user ($session['id']), you need to:

1. Get the list of the latest id of each conversation
2. Get the complete message list

I've wrote a SQL query who should do it.

```
SELECT pm.* 
FROM pm
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id_pm
      FROM pm
      WHERE pm_to={$session['id']}
      GROUP BY pm_from) DT1
ON DT1.id_pm = pm.id
ORDER BY id DESC
```